# Angular security - changing values in developer console

Tags: angularjs, security

I am creating an Angular 1 SPA. Certain controls are only visible to users with certain permissions. This is based on scope variables set by server api calls.

It occurred to me that if I could access these variables through a browsers dev console, I could change their values.

I tried this for example:

```
angular.element($0).scope().$parent.myUserInfo.accessType = "admin"
angular.element($0).scope().$apply()
```

And sure enough, the admin controls popped up on the page even though I was not logged in as an admin. Is there a best practice to stop this or am I going about it completely wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authentication **always have to be made on the server side**.

I don't know what you are trying to do, but if the user interacts with some webService/Rest API, etc... the server should disallow such interactions.

If the `accessType` property of your scope is just a way for you to know which UI you should display to the user, and the authentication/session mechanism is correctly handled by the server, that should not be a problem.

However, you cannot disallow the user to play with the dev console, so you'd better handle the authentication correctly.

Comment: The server side is handling authentication/authorisation so you're quite right, they shouldn't be able to do anything with it anyway. I just panicked when I tried it and it worked without thinking it though.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is a way of protecting values in $scope.

But as JavaScript is executed client-side and it is therefore be possible for users to modify said code, I would always verify permissions server-side. Then it wouldn't matter if users enable the admin controls client-side as they have no permission to use the api calls.